# search inside a dropdown or dropdown with a search for new set of option that user has to pick

Tags: forms, interaction-design, input-fields

what would be the better approach for an interaction which involves search inside a dropdown, where the items of the dropdown maybe new to the user and we need to show them upfront so the user can understand what to search inside the drop down

EDIT**
Scenario: The use case that I am trying to solve is picking a title(Mr, Miss...), but the challenge here is that there are almost 40 types of salutations.

Comment: do the users know what they are searching for within the dropdown, like for instance, do they know that they are searching for a place, or an event, or any other objects when interacting with the dropdown search?

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? Is it that you need to show a top 10 in the dropdown and refine the list dynamically when the user starts typing? Or are all items shown in a scrollable list and it's unclear how to make that usable? Can you add more details about how many items, what you tried so far or do you have examples that show the problem?

Comment: Same than the others: can you be more precise on the answer you are expecting? I feel like you didn't give you much information that would be really helpful to us to be able to help you. More context is the key to better answers.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest to pick the top 2/3 picks, and show them as an option even when the user has not searched anything, below that place a line and put some other options alphabetically sorted, that would give the user some context on the available options, after the user search something just show proper results, something like:

```
salutation : ______________
             Mr
             Miss
             ----------
             Dear
             Madam
             Miss


salutation : M______________
             Madam
             Miss
             Mr
```